# FileStream.ReadByte: Byte's are never negative numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, filestream

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readbyte.aspx):

> FileSystem.ReadByte
>   The byte, cast to an Int32, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

So -1 is basically a "magic value". Does this mean the bytes returned from streams are never negative? If not, why not?

Comment: For each read operation, only single byte being returned and that single byte value returned as int32. If end of file reached, then it returned as -1 (an int32 value)

Comment: you can't use Stream.ReadByte API to read byte with value -1, so if this is the case we need to use Stream.Read API with byte array as output and not confusing zero as the end of the stream return parameter :) I think this was the initial doubt of the questioner :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C# the values of a `byte` is a number between 0 and 255, so a byte is never negative.

The `sbyte` data type is a signed byte, so it has a value between -128 and 127.

(In some other languages, for example Java, the `byte` data type is signed.)

Comment: And this is the reason why in java the read method returns an integer and not a byte - because a byte could also have -1. The read returns the integer representation of the byte.

Comment: @trampi: .Net also returns an Int32 and not a byte.

Comment: @Richard DesLonde : Yep, you are right. Was only adding a note to the java comment.

Answer (score 4):

Because Bytes are not negative, they're numbers in the value 0-255.

Answer (score 4):

`byte` cannot be negative, right? It is 0...255.

Answer (score 2):

FileStream.ReadByte() returns a byte cast to an Int32 value, it returns -1 only if the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: Exact duplicate of my comment :)

Comment: if its an objective question, multiple right answers will be duplicated.

Comment: its because I answered it late and you didnt answered it at all

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: Yup, I'm in trolling mood